# Reading directories

Tags: c, linux, directory

I wrote a program that reads directories. It reads only up to level 2 of the given directory.

```
void
readDir (char *pth)
{
  char path[1000];
  strcpy (path, pth);
  DIR *dp;
  DIR *dp2;
  struct dirent *files;
  struct dirent *files2;
  if ((dp = opendir (path)) == NULL)
    perror ("dir\n");

  char newp[1000];

  struct stat buf;

  while ((files = readdir (dp)) != NULL)
    {
      if ((strcmp (files->d_name, ".") && strcmp (files->d_name, "..")))
        {
          strcpy (newp, path);
          strcat (newp, "/");
          strcat (newp, files->d_name);
          printf ("%s\n", newp);
          if ((dp2 = opendir (newp)) == NULL)
            perror ("dir\n");
          while ((files2 = readdir (dp2)) != NULL)
            {
              printf ("%s\n", files2->d_name);
              if ((strcmp (files2->d_name, ".")
                   && strcmp (files2->d_name, "..")))
                {
                  strcat (newp, "/");
                  strcat (newp, files2->d_name);
                  //printf("%s\n",newp);
                  CheckOutput (newp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of directoreis arrangement: (In each of the users directory there is one text file.)

```
Head -> user1 -> a.txt
     -> user2 -> b.txt
     -> user3 -> c.txt
```

It worked fine once, but then something weird happened: I copied txt file pasted, and deleted and it printed some weird directories like:

```
/home/Desktop/Head/user/a.txt~
/home/Desktop/Head/user/a.txt~/b.txt~
```

And I have no idea why.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you checked the directories content?

Comment: hhh, yes... a lot of times

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, you have another one though, you don't call `closedir` on `dp` and `dp2` you should call it for `dp` at the end of the outer `while` loop, and for `dp2` at the end of the inner `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tilde at the end of the filename means that this is a backup file. My assumption is that the problem is not in your code, but in the editor you used to edit the files. Editors, such as `gedit` for example, leave a backup file which is denoted by a `~` sign at the end. You should try closing the editor and running the program again.

Comment: I didnt use such an editor. I deleted the txt file using the button delete in the keyboard

Comment: I understood the problem in this print @iharob. I assumed there is one text file in each directory - but if there is a backup - there is more and i use strcat again and again

Comment: Have you checked the directory content with a file browser? Also, make sure to check the _Show hidden files_ option.

Comment: @rlf- how can i delete these backup files permenantly?

Comment: @frdfg post the answer then.

Comment: @frdfg You can try to skip them in your program.

Comment: yes i see the files in the browser!! cant delete them thought. just need to delete them now

Comment: All backup files have ~ in their end?

Comment: @frdfg you can assume that safely in your case i think.

Answer (score 0):

You should begin with initializing newp[1000] to zero with something like this :

```
char newp[1000] = {0};
```

You have problem in your loop because you use newp for both the path and the name of the files, which are two different things you have to deal with. Indeed you will have a problem at opening ./user1 then ./user2 since you overwrite newp with ./user1/a.txt~ and never cleans it.

By the way, the ~ affair may just be a backup file in the directory you launch your program with. Depending on what OS you're working on, readdir may return you hidden files from its very first call, which is most probably the case here since your file starts with an 'a'.

Find a way of creating the correct paths in your while's loop and do ls -a in your current directory.